# Weird behaviour of perl program

Tags: perl, sleep

I wrote following program

```
if(open(DATA , ">dddddddd")){
 print "creating dddddddd";
 close(DATA);
 }
 else{
    print "cannot create";
 }
 print "going to sleep";
 sleep (10);
 print "unlinking dddddddd";
 unlink "dddddddd";
```

now instead of giving output as

```
creating dddddddd  
going to sleep  
and after 10 seconds printing
unlinking dddddddd
```

it sleeps for 10 seconds when program is executed and gives output as follows

```
creating dddddddd  
going to sleep  
unlinking dddddddd.
```

can any one explain????

Comment: Why not add a carriage return at the end of your strings? For example, `print "creating dddddddd\n";`

Comment: i am using active perl on windows 7

Comment: Looks like you're [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Answer (score 4):

You might want to set [`STDOUT` to autoflush](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7c), at the beginning of your script with,

```
$| = 1;
```

or

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

Comment: Better written as  STDOUT->autoflush(1);  as it's clearer and more recognisable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have carriage returns after our print strings, so the output is probably buffered. You should add carriage returns.

For example:

```
print "creating dddddddd\r\n";
```

Or just:

```
print "creating dddddddd\n";
```